# Using CSS to allow boxes to stretch horizontally to the space given

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been pondering how to execute this in CSS. Refer to the 2 images below. Imagine a 2 column layout, where left column may or may not be longer in height than the right column and vice versa. Now in the pictures these are the green and red colours. I have a comment box and a number of boxes (plural) which could be divs that need to stretch horizontally to the space given. So when the right column is longer, the boxes start small under the left. But when the left column is longer, the boxes (still) start on the left, but obviously take up the full size.

I would like to know how to achieve this for the grey boxes in CSS. I know javascript can do it, but a css example would help.

Both FelipeAI and Daneild's code is correct. I chose FelipeAI's because his code has one less rule and yet achieves the same thing.

[image: Type 1 Situation]
[image: Type 2 Situation]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? And if so what have you tried to get this to work?

Comment: By the look of it, all you need to do it float the red box to the right to achieve that layout.

Comment: Floating the red box only changes things that can be adjusted due to their "display inline" property. Display block properties such as boxes, comment boxes or text boxes don't work the same way as far as I know.

Comment: I've tried similar things in the past, but never came up with satisfiable and elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dsScA/2/ where

- all comments begin on left,
- are constrained in width if there's a (long) right box along them
- whether left or right can be longer than the other one

I adapted @Danield code but with `clear: left` on comments and there may be as many short comments alongside the taller right box as needed (last rule removed).

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. As I commented on Danield's code. The only difference is the float:left on the .left rule. What do you think the effect can be?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/FNbc2/1/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="wpr">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right high"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="left high"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wpr
{
   width: 250px; 
}
.left,
.right {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.left {
    background: green;
    float:left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background: brown;
}
.high {
    height: 150px;
}
.comment {
    clear: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: gray;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

(css modifications adapted from @FelipAls changes to my original fiddle)

Comment: The last rule assumes that the highest box is known (it has .high class on it) and that exactly one comment (the `+` adjacent selector) following a taller right box should have reduced width. The right box may be way taller than the left one (and we don't know if it is taller or not)

Comment: @FelipeAls , true... but now it's my turn to borrow your fiddle and make some adjustments.... (I added float:left on the left div and noww it looks just like the OP wanted ;)

Comment: Thanks, the only difference between your code and FlipeAIs's code is that your .left has a float: left rule. What effect does that have? It seems that FlipeAIs's code works with float:left as well.

Answer (score 0):

Get the height of both boxes and compare them.  For the shorter one, append the additional content as often as desired (can even do some math if you want multiple items (e.g. how many of item x will fit under column a so that it is about the same size as column b).  Does that make sense?

This should get you started:

var greenheight = $('#greenone').outerHeight(),
    redheight = $('#redone').outerHeight(),
    difference = Math.abs(greenheight - redheight),
    fillerheight = $('#somehiddenfiller').outerHeight(),
    howmanyfillers = Math.floor(difference/fillerheight);

Then iterate and dump into or after the shorter one using .append()

Comment: Indeed it could be done that way. I actually only need to append to the left column. Do you know of a way to do it in CSS? The problem with using js to append to a particular column is if the heights are not evenly distributed. So even if I round it off, there'll be a inconsistent height distance between the grey boxes.

Comment: Perhaps you could always add one more box and add an overflow:auto; to the container of the grey boxes.  This way, there's content all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to play with float, padding,margin and overflow to deal with flotting elements.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xCvzq

```
    .box {
  width:445px;
  margin:auto;
  padding:15px 0 0;
  border:solid;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box > div {
  margin:0 15px 15px ;
  border:1px solid;
}
.green, .red {width:200px;}
div.green {
  height:191px;
  background:green;
  float:left;
  clear:both;
  margin-right:0;
}
.box div.first {
  height:115px;
}
div.red {
  float:right; 
  height:191px;
  background:red;
  margin-left:11px;
}
div.comment {
  overflow:hidden;
  background:gray;
  min-width:100px;
  clear:left;
}
```

Comment: Salut ;) - Comments should begin on left when the left box is taller; in your codepen they don't

Comment: :), wich browser did you use ? (just added a screenschot of what i have ) ................. never mind, i had to read twice :)